# get non-zero and not-nan elements column wise

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
```

I have a numpy array follows:

```
data = np.array([[2,3,4,5,0,7,8,9,9,3,np.nan],
                 [3,3,6,5,0,7,9,9,9,3,1],
                 [2,6,4,5,0,7,9,9,9,4,1]])
print (data)
```

I wanted to get the data from where all numbers (column wise) are not 0; and from where any elements are not np.nan.

```
indices = np.any(data, axis=1)

print (data[indices])
```

expected is:

```
[[2 3 4 5 7 8 9 9 3]
 [3 3 6 5 7 9 9 9 3]
 [2 6 4 5 7 9 9 9 4]]
```

I tried as mask as follows.

```
mask = np.all(np.isnan(data) | np.equal(data, 0), axis=1)

print (data[~mask])



[[ 2.  3.  4.  5.  0.  7.  0.  9.  9.  3. nan]
 [ 3.  3.  6.  5.  0.  7.  9.  9.  9.  3.  1.]
 [ 2.  6.  4.  5.  0.  7.  9.  9.  9.  4.  1.]]
```

but not expected result

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html

Comment: Use any along `axis=0` for columns and then use it for column-indexing - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: please show me code, i could not make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use np.any along the columns (axis=0). Combine this with not any np.isnan
This will return column indices where any value in that column is not zero and there are no nans.
Then use these to index the original array.

```
mask = ~np.any(np.isnan(data),axis=0) &  np.any(data, axis=0)
indices=data[:,mask]
```

Comment: can `[:,np.any(data,axis=0)]` is obtained as true and false. I need to make it one linner with np.nan (get any not np.nan elements only).

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot remove all nan and all zero columns in a single line of code. You can make a mask. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032668/numpy-drop-rows-with-all-nan-or-0-values

Comment: IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 11

Comment: `data.T[np.any(data, axis=0)].T`

Comment: @wwii The question asker is trying to remove columns with at least one nan value as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
data[:,(~np.isnan(data)).all(axis=0)&~(data==0).any(axis=0)].astype("int")
```

Output:

```py
[[2 3 4 5 7 8 9 9 3]
 [3 3 6 5 7 9 9 9 3]
 [2 6 4 5 7 9 9 9 4]]
```

Comment: how can i combine, `data[:,np.any(data,axis=0)]` and `data[:,(~np.isnan(data)).all(axis=0)])` together?

Comment: But this is your expected output? Why would you combine it then? They do different things

Comment: to make one liner

Comment: The first one takes all columns where there's at least one non-nan element, whereas the second takes all columns, where all elements are not-nan.

Comment: Ok, what is then your expected output?

Comment: `[[2 3 4 5 7 8 9 9 3]
 [3 3 6 5 7 9 9 9 3]
 [2 6 4 5 7 9 9 9 4]]`

Comment: That's exactly what this code does - I converted it to ```int``` to be 100% like your expected output

Comment: i also need to remove `0`

Comment: Gotcha! This one I didn't get- now it's added!